# How can I pull an update out of a transaction to be done later?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a transaction that gets some data, inserts some data and does an update on one table.  This updated table is causing some Oracle locking so I want to take the update out of this transaction and start a new transaction at the end of my process to do the update.

So currently I get the updated table in a join and then I, update some data in the object and then at the end of the transaction, hibernate does it's magic and updates the table.  I want to change that, I think, to get the data at the beginning of the transaction, detach the object, update the data in the object, and then do a merge() in a new transaction.  Possible?  I can't figure out how to Detach it as  the HibernateTemplate does not have a detach() method.

Not sure if this matters, but I have a one-to-one association:

```
 <one-to-one name="itmInstSum" class="dds.tmatic.domain.ItmInstSum" fetch="join"  />
```

Any ideas?  Am I not understanding detach?  I believe evict() removes it from the cache or something and that is not what I want to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: In the commit() method Hibernate rearrange the order of the database statements which sometimes produces unwanted results. With `Session.flush()` you can influence this behaviour. Hibernate only rearrange statements between two flush() statements (commit() implicitly calls flush()).

Second: Hibernate does not have a detach, but it has the `Session.evict()` method, which takes the object out of the control of Hibernate. If you want to put it under control of Hibernate again and merge it, then you have to load the object from the database again and merge it be copying the modified properties manually.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried this and it works. So I am evict()ing the object, then when the transaction finishes, I start a new one and merge() it.  Perfect!